# How to see the previous date/time for a Google Calendar event that was moved?

Tags: google-calendar

Suppose someone invited me to an event using Google Calendars. Some time later, they moved the event, and I accepted the move. Now, I want to see what the previous date and time of the event was, before they moved it.

Let's assume the original "Invitation" email is either unavailable (for example, deleted completely, not archived or in trash), or doesn't contain the information I need (e.g. it was an instance of a recurring event but it's not possible for me to figure out the previous date and time from other events in the series).

How can I see what the date and time for the event was, before it was moved?